# What does --with-extension in php compiling do?

Tags: php, compilation

I've just learnt how to compile php modules and things but I'm unsure of something.

My OS X comes with php 5.4.17 and it seems to have various extensions in it without any .sos anywhere (pdo_sqlite, pdo_mysql, curl etc)

If I compile php --with-extension, is that extension then built into the php binaries without need for adding in php? Or something similar.

E.g. I compiled **pdo_sqlite** and **pdo_mysql** and it warned that I was trying to include them twice. I unincluded them from php.ini and checked `phpinfo()` and they were already enabled and nowhere on my system.

I can only assume that the configure command put them in the binaries.

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

check your phpinfo() output page, whether you have this:
**Scan this dir for additional .ini files**
**Additional .ini files parsed**

most probably **pdo_sqlite** and **pdo_mysql** are already defined in the **Additional .ini files parsed**

after running `./configure --with-extension`, run `grep Configured config.log`, you will see the actual configure options used

Comment: Scan this dir for additional .ini files /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed (none). The directory it scans for doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

`--with-extension` enables the specified extension in your custom php build.

For example

```
--with-apx2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
```

enables apache2 server installed at location `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs`